# Decoding a JWSTransaction from Apple Store API using Java

Tags: jwt

Does anyone have working Java code for decoding a JWSTransaction, as returned from the Apple App Store API?  I'm not a security expert.

I started with JJWT. So far I have this from their sample code and modified based on other articles. Not sure if I'm even on the right path. Any help, much appreciated.

```
private String appleApiKeyPathP8 = "c:\\apple-api-key.p8";
private String transaction = "xxx.yyy.zzz";

public void decodeAppleJwt()
{
    Jws<Claims> jws;
    
    try 
    {
        byte[] p8der = Files.readAllBytes( new File( appleApiKeyPathP8 ).toPath() );
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec priPKCS8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec( java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode( p8der ) );
        PrivateKey appleKey = KeyFactory.getInstance( "EC" ).generatePrivate( priPKCS8 );

        jws = Jwts.parserBuilder()                  // (1)
                // .setKeyLocator( keyLocator )     // (2) dynamically lookup verification keys based on each JWS    
                .setSigningKey( appleKey )          //     or a static key used to verify all encountered JWSs              
                .build()                            // (3)
                .parseClaimsJws( transaction );     // (4) or parseContentJws(jwsString)      
    }
    catch( JwtException e ) 
    {       
        System.out.println( "JwtException:" + e.getMessage() );
    }
    catch( Exception e ) 
    {       
        System.out.println( "Exception:" + e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Note output from the above is:

JwtException:The parsed JWT indicates it was signed with the 'ES256' signature algorithm, but the provided sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl key may not be used to verify ES256 signatures.  Because the specified key reflects a specific and expected algorithm, and the JWT does not reflect this algorithm, it is likely that the JWT was not expected and therefore should not be trusted.  Another possibility is that the parser was provided the incorrect signature verification key, but this cannot be assumed for security reasons.